# What caused the change in Darth Maul?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious, darth-maul

In the Star Wars franchise, the role of Darth Maul changes and I'm wondering why both within the story but also outside it. **In other words, has Dave Filoni, et al, given any insight on this?** I ask this because, when I compare this story with most of the rest of the writing, it lacks the detail, plausibility, and subtlety that makes the series loved so much.

That would be as implausible as Anakin waking up one day and deciding "Yeah, I got this great wife, am a general, can do pretty much anything. You know what, think I'll just be evil from now on". Or Snips starting off as arrogant and impulsive, being told to change, and then just changing from that point on. That would boring, the writers clearly knew that, and [planned from the beginning for a transformative arc](https://youtu.be/msgQ6WbIHyc?t=49)

With Maul, he's little more than the assassin-apprentice who was selected for brutality, trained solely for cruelty, used for violence, and then went insane after being cut in half and left to die. Yet, when he comes back he's now much more cerebral. Rather than just show up and start slashing, Maul is introspective, inquisitive, patient, and has the capability to lay intricate plans. That change is not only really abrupt, it simply doesn't seem plausible.

The rationale of this newfound intellectual capability being *due to* insanity just doesn't strike me as plausible either considering how the story evolved. Maul is selected for physical capabilities, force sensitivity, and really importantly, the sort who would use hate and anger to fuel himself. To expect him to reassess the long-term effects of his methodology and perhaps check with Sith-HR to see if he is eligible for Sith-anger management classes so he can approach things differently -- well, that sounds funny but would ultimately be discarded as BS.

Comment: This seems like the exact opposite of insanity. Maul tried the straightforward brute-force approach, lost badly, and learned to be more thoughtful as a result. It seems to me insanity would be *continuing* the approach that got you cut in half!

Comment: That really doesn't seem plausible without you doing the writers' job yourself. I mean, I'm willing to chalk all sorts of stuff happening because it was "A long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away" but if we have to make up stuff like how Zabrak males are {fill in the blank}, or maybe {fill in the blank}, then something may be wrong. I just want to know what the writers thought since they have a history of good writing for this series.

Comment: The change is abrupt from the point of view of a viewer of the series, from his appearance in *The Phantom Menace* to his re-emergence in *The Clone Wars*, however that span represents a 10 year timeskip during which time he was in self-exile in the Outer Rim. When you look at it that way, having a full decade means it's not abrupt at all.

Comment: Maul's problem in his youth was in controlling his emotions, not a lack of intellect. He was obviously smart enough to go out on solo missions several times for Sidious before the events of TPM, which included formulating plans, and adapting to the situation around him. He also had time, before and after his insanity, to reflect on his life. It's not really that unbelievable that he could grow in wisdom and restraint with experience, as most people do in the real world, especially with already possessing a fair amount of cunning, even if it was sometimes overborne by bloodlust.

Comment: So these are all good hypotheses but what I'd like to know is what, if anything, the writers said.

Answer (score 3):

**Mother Talzin cured Darth Maul**

From Wookieepedia:

[On Darth Maul being insane](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Brothers):

> Down in the tunnels beneath the junk, Opress is stalked and attacked by a spider-like creature who is eventually revealed to be an emaciated and *deranged* Maul, transformed into a centauroid half-spider cyborg. Morley takes this inopportune moment to reappear, asking for "leftovers," and under Opress' tight grip reveals that while he did exploit Maul for his own gain, it was not him who had turned him into a cyborg or left him in his current *insane* state, before he is choked to death. When Opress talks to him, Maul tells him in between his mad *ravings* about how he was *reduced to this pitiful state* and that he seeks revenge on the Jedi, especially the one who did this to him.

[On Mother Talzin curing Darth Maul](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Talzin?so=search):

> Shortly after the massacre, Opress returned to Dathomir having successfully retrieved a *crazed* and crippled Maul. Using what magicks she had left, Talzin reconstructed her son and *restored his broken mind*.
>
> The act of restoring Maul forced Talzin to surrender her physical body to the spirit realm, but her son pledged to carry her torch of vengeance in a quest to draw out and kill Dooku and Sidious.

This is also corroborated on StarWars.com

> Savage was eventually successful, using Talzin’s magick to lead him to the crazed and broken shell of Maul. Savage brought his lost brother back to Dathomir, delivering him to Talzin so the magical matriarch could cure him of his madness and replace his cybernetic spider appendages with bipedal legs, restoring the former Sith to his full power at the cost of some of her own life energy. Maul, son of Dathomir, was reborn.
>
> Talzin held a special fondness for Maul over the rest of her children; her thirst for vengeance was fueled by the inciting act of Darth Sidious taking Maul away to train as his apprentice after he recognized the youth’s connection to the Force and potential as a Sith.

The [scene from  Clone Wars: Season 4 Episode 21](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I5-gBOWxHoo&ab_channel=CloneWarsClips)